# OpenCL Local Memory Declaration

Tags: opencl, gpu

What is the difference between declaring local memory as follows:

```
__kernel void mmul(const int Ndim, const int Mdim, const int Pdim,
                      const __global int* A,
                      const __global int* B,
                     __global char* C,
                     __local int* restrict block_a,
                     __local int* restrict block_b)
```

and declaring local memory inside the kernel

```
#define a_size 1024
#define b_size 1024 * 1024
__kernel void mmul(const int Ndim, const int Mdim, const int Pdim,
                      const __global int* A,
                      const __global int* B,
                     __global char* C) {

__local int block_a[a_size]
__local int block_b[b_size]

... 
}
```

In both cases, all threads will update a single cell in the shared A and B arrays

I understand that it's not possible to have "variable" length arrays in the kernel (hence the #define at the top of the second kernel), but is there any other difference? Is there any difference with regards to when the memory is freed?

Comment: define local memory in a kernel means, that it is going to be allocated for each work group. having local memory as parameter means, that anywhere before the memory was allocated and also for each workgroup it's the same pointer. Don't think of when and if memory is freed. OpenCL is like 1. compiling 2. call a kernel with how many groups and workers 3. implicitly now knowing how much memory will be used.

Comment: Optimization Tip: "If every thread is just reading and writing to one single position of the local memory. Why do you even need local memory?"

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, local memory exists for the lifetime of the work-group. The only difference, as you have noted, is that passing the local memory pointer as an argument allows the size of the buffer to be specified dynamically, rather than being a compile-time constant. Different work-groups will always use different local memory allocations.

Comment: Nit picking but it also make a difference if you call clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo with the CL_KERNEL_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE flag. In the first case the size will be assumed to be 0. In the second case it'll return the correct size...

Answer (score 1):

The  second method is better if you want to port code to CUDA, because the `__shared__` memory in CUDA (equivalent to  `__local` in OpenCL) does not support to be declared like the first case.